# json to csv in python

Tags: python, json, csv

```
{"event":
[
    {"query":
        {"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429853503915728"}],
         "query_text":"Upkar Layout, Bengaluru, Karnataka"}},
         {"`enter code here`query":{"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429807631122125"}],
         "query_text":"niit business analytics"}},
    {"query":
        {"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429806395505907"}],
         "query_text":"respectsale ads remove"}},
    {"query":
        {"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429805470962089"}],
         "query_text":"allen a 85 india"}},
    {"query":
        {"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429802977766436"}],
        "query_text":"respectsale chrome"}},
    {"query":
        {"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429802946542177"}],
        "query_text":"test"}},
    {"query":
    {"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429802439164745"}],
    "query_text":"blah"}},
    {"query":{"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429801620233735"}],
    "query_text":"respectsale adware remove"}},
    {"query":{"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429801588436261"}],
    "query_text":"test"}},
    {"query":{"id":[{"timestamp_usec":"1429796953341667"}],
```

that's how my json data looks like.
I need to convert it to csv using python.
i am absolutely new to python. 
Please Help!! 
Thanks

Comment: am sorry i dont have a code. i dont even know where to begin!

Comment: So what do you expect from us ? Python has a fairly extensive tutorial and documentation, perhaps you could start here, try and start something and come back when you have a real question ?

Comment: Google web history.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice library called:

[json2csv](https://github.com/evidens/json2csv)

And the equivilent oppositive `csv2json` from:

[csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/)

**Example:** (*json2csv*)

```
python json2csv.py /path/to/json_file.json /path/to/outline_file.json -o /some/other/file.csv
```